# Sails.js query on an associated value

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

I'm using Sails.js version `0.10.0-rc4`. All models are using sails-mysql.

I'm trying to query a model which has an "one-to-many" association to another model (the query is happening on the "many" side).

It looks something like this:

```
Post.find()
    .where({ category: category_id })
    .populate("category")
    .exec( ... )
```

This gives me an empty array back however when I leave out the `.populate("category")` I get the correct result set.

I know that I could leave `.populate("category")` out and then fetch each correlating Category object separately, but I'm wondering if there's a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 12):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do here.  If your goal is to filter the categories that get populated on the `Post`, you can do:

```
Post.find()
    .populate("category", {where: { category: category_id }})
    .exec( ... )
```

If you want to only retrieve `Post`s with a certain category, you would do:

```
Category.findOne(category_id)
        .populate("posts")
        .exec(function(e, c) {console.log(c.posts);})
```

Comment: The second snippet does the job. I'd like to get posts in a specific category. The problem is that I run a bunch of different queries on this route (get posts by name, get posts by viewcount etc). Therefore I'd like to be able to query "get posts by category" in a similar fashion. Do you know if that's doable?

Comment: Running into same scenario..
Btw, @scott this works only for one-to-one association?

Comment: Same issue here too. This works only for one-to-one associations and not for one-to-many or many-to-may. @Lujaw, did you find a solution?

Comment: The first snippet is not working for me on many to many associations.

Answer (score 1):

*Original post was too soon*

Following works for me (sails 0.12) with population:

```
Post.find({category: category_id})
    .populate("category")
    .exec( ... )
```

But I am still puzzled who to search in a subquery any other attribute than id..

Edit2: Seems like deep query is not yet supported: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/266