# Cannot find using self reference associations in Waterline - Sails.js - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, tree, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to create a tree structure using associations in Waterline which in the end connects to a MongoDB database. The definition of a treee no is:

TreeNode.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: 'string',
        childrenCategory: 'string',
        parent: {
            model: 'TreeNode'
        },
        children: {
            collection: 'TreeNode',
            via: 'parent'
        }
    }
};
```

And that's it for my tree structure. This node reference itself having multiple childrens of the same node and a unique parent, again of the same node. 
Populating these tree seems to be working. But trying to find node with a given 'parent' does not. The following query gives nothing:

```
TreeNode.find().where({parent: someId}).exec(function (err, r) {}
```

Any ideas? Also, what do you think about this tree structure?
Thanks!

Comment: The query is not matching to the data structure you have shown. Where is the parent ID stored in your documents?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer on another post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22942987/3336235)

Comment: Thanks fot the responses. Sebastina, as "parent" is a reference to the same document (TreeNode) the id will be that of the master document. I did not declare "id" because is auto generated, so it should be there.

Comment: The difference in the post suggested, is that in that they use references between 2 diffrent documents and this is a reference to itselft. I don't know if this is possible really, I did not found anything about trees on Waterline.

Comment: This should absolutely work.  Can you post some code where you're creating TreeNode instances?  Maybe the problem is there.  Remember that just adding `children` to an instance won't set the `parent` attribute of those nodes; you'll have to set manually...and vice versa...

Comment: I have a more detailed explanation on a GitHub thread with Waterline creator. Check https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/410#issuecomment-42330400

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post:

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/410

Will it help you if you try using `objectid` as the type for the parent?