# SailsJS relations not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

SailsJS with MongoDB adapter not working as expected. I have following relations defined:

### Post.js:

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mongodb',

  attributes: {
    title: 'string',
    categories: {
      collection: 'postCategory',
      via: 'posts'
    }
  }
};
```

### PostCategory.js

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mongodb',

  attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    posts: {
      collection: 'post',
      via: 'categories'
    }
  }
};
```

When I query without criteria and populate `categories` like:

```
Post.find()
       .populate('categories')
       .then(...)
```

it gives me correct result, the document has categories nested.

But when I try to pass criteria it returns no result. e.g.

```
Post.find({categories: 'food'})
       .populate('categories')
       .then(...)
```

Note: I inserted category `_id` as string (food, travel, etc) in database

Please help

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940626/sails-js-query-on-a-associated-value)

Answer (score 1):

You will not get any results because in `categories` it will store the `_id`.

You can get the results by doing the following query.

```
PostCategory.find({name: 'food'})
       .populate('posts')
       .then(...)
```

Comment: As I said before `_id` is the string `food`, but not getting records

Comment: @mahadazad can you add the records from the mongodb to the question.